# python output system calls to terminal and logfile

Tags: python, stdout, system-calls

I would like to execute system calls from my (python) script such that the output of the sys-call is generated on the terminal where script is running as well as is captured in a logfile. However I am not able to make this work for interactive system calls.

I started with following code that does not capture the system call in a logfile, but works correctly (as in is able to display output on terminal, and can take inputs I type in terminal) for both basic commands such as `system('echo HEYA')` as well as interactive commands such as `system('python')` :

```
def system(cmd):
    log.info(f"Running: {cmd}")
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd,  check=True, shell=True, executable=SHELL)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        log.error(err.output)
```

Notes: `log` is a logger (created using standard `logging` module). `SHELL` variable holds a shell of my choice.

Now, I modify the above to be able to redirect the process output to terminal as well as logfile on disk in realtime with following code:

```
def system(cmd):
    log.info(f"Running: {cmd}")
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                             shell=True, executable=SHELL, universal_newlines=True, 
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while True:
            o = process.stdout.readline().rstrip('\n')
            if o == ''  and process.poll() is not None:
                break
            if o:
                syslog.info(o)
        ret = process.poll()
        if ret:
            log.error(f"Failed with exit code: {ret}")
        else:
            log.info("Done")
    except:
        err = sys.exc_info()[0]
        log.error(err)
        raise
```

Notice that I use a different logger (`syslog`) to redirect outputs to logfile and terminal. The only reason for this, is I want system command outputs formatted differently from other messages generated in the script.

The second version of `system` function works for something like `system('echo HEYA')` but not for interactive calls like `system('python')`. Any suggestions what I may be doing wrong, and how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on an earlier post of similar nature:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/651718/5150258

I was able to get this work partially by using first form of system definition with a tee:

```
tee = subprocess.Popen(["tee", "sys_cmds.log"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
os.dup2(tee.stdin.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(tee.stdin.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno()
def system(cmd):
    log.info(f"Running: {cmd}")
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd,  check=True, shell=True, executable=SHELL)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        log.error(err.output)
```

However this isn't the perfect solution since I lose formatting control of the output as it goes directly without passing through the logger object.