# Capture everything, not just print statements, that is printed by Python

Tags: python

As mentioned above,I would like to capture everything that is printed on the screen by Python to a file.

I've found [these great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file), but they all use more or less the same approach and don't capture everything. Specifically I try to capture the output of `YouTubeDL`, the Python package, not the command line tool, but it's not saved if I just capture `sys.stdout`.

P.S.: I'm using Windows.

Comment: Do you know how it's generating its output? If it's writing to `sys.stderr`, you can capture that the same way. But if it's writing to `/dev/tty` you'll need to use a pseudo-tty.

Comment: @Barmar I'm capturing `sys.stderr` as well. It's just used for exceptions.

Comment: On Unix there's the `script` command that captures all the input and output of a terminal application. Maybe there's something analogous on Windows.

Comment: @Barmar I could run it externally and capture it via `>>` and `2>>`, but I want to solve it in Python.

Comment: If `>>` works externally, then reassigning `sys.stdout` should work.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. It would be logical, but sadly it's not like that.

Comment: Is YouTubeDL open source? Check the source code to see what it's doing that gets around this redirection.

Comment: @Barmar The point is: I'm looking for a general solution that covers everything. `YouTubeDL` was just the reason and an example. But yes, it's open source! :)

Comment: For practically everything, redirecting `sys.stdout` should work. There's something very weird about YouTubeDL. Without knowing what it is, it's hard to come up with a general solution that also handles it.