# How to get last python output?

Tags: python, printing, console, output

I´m trying to get last python output and I dont know how to do it.

Basically what Iím trying to do is detect the last output so, for example:

```
print("Hello World")
last_output = get_last_output()
print() # For avoiding confutions

print(last_output)
# Would print "\n"


print("Hello World", end="")
last_output = get_last_output()
print() # For avoiding confutions

print(last_output)
# Would print "Hello World"
```

I would also love this awnser would work independently of the console

Comment: Do you want `subprocess.check_output`? It's basically `Popen` but it's sync and blocks your code until it finishes.

Comment: It "does" or "doesn't" seem to work? If it "doesn't", what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @EricJin how would you use it in this case? I did not understand its documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych they do not print the latest output in the file, they just print in bytes the current's file path

Comment: I see now, so you want to capture the output to stdout of the last function that was run? You're going to need to read from `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Yes, how can I use `sys.stdout` to read always from the last line of the output?

Comment: You would probably need to seek backwards until you hit a newline. Or use `readlines` and take the last one.

Comment: I have tried and can seem to make it work, can you show me how would you do it? @EricJin

Comment: Nevermind, you're not able to read from stdout. But you can execute whole python files with it and check the output. What is your objective anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming *"the last output"* is the last **not empty string written to `sys.stdout`**, one option is to assign an object with the `write(data)` and `flush()` methods to `sys.stdout`, so you can save what should be the output:

```py
import sys


class StdoutHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_output = ""
    
    def start(self):
        self._handled_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self
    
    def write(self, data: str):
        # write(data="") is called for the end kwarg in print(..., end="")
        if data:
            self.last_output = data
            self._handled_stdout.write(data)

    def end(self):
        sys.stdout = self._handled_stdout
    
    def flush(self):
        self._handled_stdout.flush()



stdout_handler = StdoutHandler()
stdout_handler.start()


print("Hello World")
last_output = stdout_handler.last_output
print(repr(last_output))
# Prints '\n'


print("Hello World", end="")
last_output = stdout_handler.last_output
print()
print(repr(last_output))
# Prints 'Hello World'

print("Hello", "World", end="")
last_output = stdout_handler.last_output
print()
print(repr(last_output))
# Prints 'World'
```

> I got the idea from [*How to duplicate sys.stdout to a log file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/19317456)

> Disclaimer: @Baelfire18 asked me to help him answer this question

Comment: This is such a cool idea! 

Comment: I don't have control of the end character in the printing message, so I always get "\n"... How could I obtain the before the last message in this case?

Comment: @phasselmann you could replace `last_output` with a [deque from collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), using maxlen to avoid storing every string. With that, you could store the output with append, and access previous messages with negative indexing.

Comment: do you mean replacing it in " def __init__(self): self.last_output = deque() " and then how would I do it in "def write(self, data: str)" ?

Comment: @phasselmann with `self.last_output.append(data)`, like mentioned in my previous comment.