# C# file copy error file is being used by another program

Tags: c#

I have a directory where i make/place some files.
When the filesystemwatcher sees a new file it copy's that file in a second directory.
But when i create a file directly in dir1 then it shuts down saying it is used by another program.

How do i get rid of this problem?

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ChaloSync
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool pause = false;
    String source = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Directory1"];
    String target = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Directory2"];

    private void start()
    {
        pause = true;
        Start.Text = "Pause";
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }



    static void config()
    {
        foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
        {
            string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            File.Copy(e.FullPath , Path.Combine(target,e.Name));
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = source;
        if (!pause)
        {
            start();
        }
        else
        {
            pause = false;
            Start.Text = "Start";
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;   

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same problem, but caused by the same. The solution can be good for you.

> A typical problem of this approach is that the file is still being
>   copied while the event is triggered. Obviously, you will get an
>   exception because the file is locked during copying. An exception is
>   especially likely on large files.
>
> As a workaround you could first copy the file and then rename it and
>   listen to the renaming event.
>
> Or another option would be to have a while loop checking whether the
>   file can be opened with write access. If it can you will know that
>   copying has been completed. C# code could look like this (in a
>   production system you might want to have a maximum number of retries
>   or timeout instead of a while(true)):

(Copied from here: [File access error with FileSystemWatcher when multiple files are added to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699538/file-access-error-with-filesystemwatcher-when-multiple-files-are-added-to-a-dire))

Comment: You need to imeplement (insert) WaitReady method before you copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have experienced locked issue when read or write a file, please check `FileShare` option.

Please kindly check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721059/361100).

Answer (score 1):

Renaming and Creating are being done at the same time. So you can't copy it because it's already being used to rename it at that moment..