# Python - Only last line is saved to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to output the result of my script into a text file. The script is working fine, the only problem is when results are saved into the text file (output.txt), only last line is being saved,not the whole thing? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. any suggestions will be appreciated.

Cheer!

```
        try:

            if 'notavailable' not in requests.get('url' + str(service) + '&username=' + str(username), headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}).text:
                result = service + '\t' + " > " + username + " > " 'Available'
                print  result
                f = open("output.txt", "w")              
                f.write(result + "\n")
                f.close()

            else:
                print service + '\t' + " > " + username + " > " 'Not Available'

        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

Comment: Well, you code only writes one line of data, that `result` variable. So how were you expecting anything larger to end up in the file? Is this maybe inside a loop that you haven't shown us?

Comment: Maybe `result` variable contains only `one line of data` that is why your file contains only one line. 

what is the result of `print result` statement?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `open("output.txt", "a")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to write

```
f = open("output.txt", "a")
```

This will append the file, rather than write over whatever else you put in it.

Answer (score 4):

In every iteration you are opening the file, erasing its content, writing and closing. It is much better to open it only once:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
# do loop
    f.write(stuff)
f.close()
```

Or, much better:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    while loop:
       f.write(stuff)
```

This method is not only cleaner, but also performs much better, as you can cache the contents of the file, and use the minimal number of OS calls.

Comment: if for any reason whatsoever it is absolutely necessary to close the file every time, use 'a' inside the loop instead of 'w', and it will work as well.
If however you run the program a second time, this will append to the existing file, so pay attention for that as well.

Comment: @ShadowFlame, how do you open the file only once if you use `f.write` for something like an error log?

Comment: you open before the loop, you close after the loop. look at the first example in this answer, it is a perfect example

Comment: That completely wouldn't work for the use case I am referring to.  On a web server, I'm not going to just leave a file open indefinitely; I want to open it for a specific purpose and only for that specific purpose.  Your example would work for a single procedure run once (and is exactly how you should do it for that use), not for dynamically editing a log file, which is exactly why the append exists.  Of course, this isn't to say that this is the best/only way to handle error reporting, but that is a different question entirely.

Comment: @Dave I disagree. Precisely, you want logging to happen as fast as possible, and opening and closing takes time. Also, releasing the file may cause interferences with a backup system. See [this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164053/should-log-file-streams-be-opened-closed-on-each-write-or-kept-open-during-a-des) For this case, open it with the option `buffering=0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and assume that all of this code happens inside a loop. Each time through the loop, you write one more line, but at the end, you only have the last line.

If that's the problem, here's the issue:

```
        f = open("output.txt", "w")
```

When you open a file in `'w'` mode, that truncates any existing file.

To fix this, either open the file once, outside the loop, instead of over and over again, or open it in `'a'` mode or `'r+'` mode or some other mode that doesn't truncate the file.

The documentation for the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function, or the inline help in the interactive interpreter, explains what all the different modes mean.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with parameter 'a' 
So:
f = open("output.txt", "a")

That will open the file with pointer at the end.
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python