# Python: Only last row in list of dictionaries is getting written to file

Tags: python

I have a HAR file which looks like this:

```
'Host': 'deal.ig.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'x-device-user-agent': 'vendor=IG Group | applicationType=ig | platform=WTP | deviceType=Win32 | view=chart | version=0.3923.0+6a372d26', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'cst': '91a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'Cookie': 'optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1583408158372r0.31262903776855944; _ga=GA1.2.3213041.1583408160; _gid=GA1.2.77060031.1583408160; _gat=1; AMCVS_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C50579323134050101141167903551723140495; _gcl_au=1.1.105363083.1583408170; _gat_UA-53269626-3=1; _gali=loginbutton; adviggroupigcomuklive=1; s_cvp_mktch19=%5B%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174937%27%5D%5D; s_nr2=1583408174936-New; gpv_pn=ex%20nav%3Alogin; s_cc=true; s_cvp_mktch28=%5B%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174934%27%5D%2C%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174947%27%5D%5D; ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9BQ0NFU1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAifQ.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOvQrCMBQF4He5c4fcNMlNuomL0kFoXYo4pPkpgRrFtiCI724mwTN-HA7nDda5-5bXBZoLtAO1HVwrcHMKeT16aAAZcpRGc6hgW8Iz21sofNh13aB1zQrv-3MRgxY9c2RHNDUPyhjyyqGMEckQSus41dbjKJ0XQWnhOSkXzWhZEMpHhiVlLdkVGpS6FkwjyQJLOQd9ytMc-jTlUy6tPMb_Vng9fiBIfr50IW8W2gAAAA.qGsWbnN0LzmeCKkepN0vWY4z1sOYO6SgvNoPcQR3o6_6h8-5obpfQ_O1UQT1EOsPCxHJgibmX0_eHI8ll4gkY5oq75692T-1UU4nYJoXXW-iP1kNX-bV1Kba-sJybFWOywO_hp9wqKdko7jDGg7Ax8Q6JWb478enYZ8Y3VB2tzLMNMpK-J0RJyVt9_DRzkhvlguB7z1WdZluk5AD-z6mnX4SeUmzY2VjaOlRybp2oudUbGzwft5PiVlyVs8-O8oBr_EwKdG8O5Hnxzfg5GRThfTPzjuha02CgXi1M892AlBqnU7RCc39I8vNH5XPEcyow_RghDjb4k1VSR-mZtiMCw; CST=91a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111; ID=TD=DB400FA09853FBF32BD51785C67BDB2F2EEB2D75:CS=2:A=1; IG-ENVIRONMENT=PROD; REFRESH-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9SRUZSRVNIIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ6aXAiOiJHWklQIn0.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXMuwoCMRCF4XdJbZFJMrlsJzZaCbs2lrlMlsAaxF1BEN_dKWw85cfhf4u8NOrbqYhBgAQFGLwSO_Fc6dHjjZiP-3G8eq8l82G6sASIUGR2MUHQimwIrtgMWCu44ABjVk7HAglzMWS9KcrZXEOKkowtVQKPay1uYgD02kgPDhnWlfNT6_NCU5v7ufOrp_r_otf9Bwja4ecLU4FikcUAAAA.CfStuGzJg4E4cDWuroNg5rj1vMsfmYjbkJfexIVfylwhBO_0WRiDQlyZ0G3RULW_6VpsQsR3qXj3UslUh79XY96fuCfLjFO5mP9EPO32j2Q72_WaT7NTb5HnTHv1xbblYwSOQwPraMaYwYkrDys14p5EDlPGNm9p3WXrk1s7-GZrvwryqcTgUfltvha2A_CG8odvzUqwP5ZTvs6Ua9fGDc7XTCAbmXq8IlutVCSNeR-8N10dfGVwzAsDe-wzEsGG3lDPuGbZuc29GgQIFpjEsVZuL0bw_JhiV57eknUBOC3NdsDSWk8p765Ex3V3SxT72Y0OUcZelteFLmWnUZNAgA; callerReqId=a122ee92484fefdd; client_id=a20fa8511e2a302574dddc5533444d0b; defaultDealingPlatform=PUREDEAL; deviceOs=Other; deviceType=Desktop; exitPath=uk; exitUrl=https://www.ig.com/uk; preferredAccountId=KY7KR; sessionOpen=true; AMCV_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18327%7CMCMID%7C50579323134050101141167903551723140495%7CMCAAMLH-1584012984%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1584012984%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1583415384s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18334%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2%7CMCCIDH%7C-1029498915; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; cpaEnabled=true; AAMC_iggroup_0=REGION%7C6; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10776225%2Caam%3D10776328%2Caam%3D10873328%2Caam%3D10873753%2Caam%3D10554416%2Caam%3D10800273%2Caam%3D10800207%2Caam%3D12237189%2Caam%3D14258131%2Caam%3D16895981%2Caam%3D11348465%2Caam%3D17467451; linkedinexcl=seg%3D10554416; aam_uuid=54084551990277770212092742170574063792; X-SECURITY-TOKEN=283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111; session_start_time=1583408194012; wtp:session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Aplatform%22%2C%22cst%22%3A%2291a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111%22%2C%22xst%22%3A%22283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111%22%7D%7D; lang=en-GB', 'ig-account-id': 'KY7KR', 'x-security-token': '283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'Accept': '*/*'}
{'Host': 'deal.ig.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'x-device-user-agent': 'vendor=IG Group | applicationType=ig | platform=WTP | deviceType=Win32 | view=chart | version=0.3923.0+6a372d26', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'CST': '91a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'X-Transaction-Id': 'htmlcharts_66dc4433-97a1-4fe8-a87a-22b8a71e1c35', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'X-SECURITY-TOKEN': '283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'Cookie': 'optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1583408158372r0.31262903776855944; _ga=GA1.2.3213041.1583408160; _gid=GA1.2.77060031.1583408160; _gat=1; AMCVS_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C50579323134050101141167903551723140495; _gcl_au=1.1.105363083.1583408170; _gat_UA-53269626-3=1; _gali=loginbutton; adviggroupigcomuklive=1; s_cvp_mktch19=%5B%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174937%27%5D%5D; s_nr2=1583408174936-New; gpv_pn=ex%20nav%3Alogin; s_cc=true; s_cvp_mktch28=%5B%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174934%27%5D%2C%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174947%27%5D%5D; ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9BQ0NFU1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAifQ.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOvQrCMBQF4He5c4fcNMlNuomL0kFoXYo4pPkpgRrFtiCI724mwTN-HA7nDda5-5bXBZoLtAO1HVwrcHMKeT16aAAZcpRGc6hgW8Iz21sofNh13aB1zQrv-3MRgxY9c2RHNDUPyhjyyqGMEckQSus41dbjKJ0XQWnhOSkXzWhZEMpHhiVlLdkVGpS6FkwjyQJLOQd9ytMc-jTlUy6tPMb_Vng9fiBIfr50IW8W2gAAAA.qGsWbnN0LzmeCKkepN0vWY4z1sOYO6SgvNoPcQR3o6_6h8-5obpfQ_O1UQT1EOsPCxHJgibmX0_eHI8ll4gkY5oq75692T-1UU4nYJoXXW-iP1kNX-bV1Kba-sJybFWOywO_hp9wqKdko7jDGg7Ax8Q6JWb478enYZ8Y3VB2tzLMNMpK-J0RJyVt9_DRzkhvlguB7z1WdZluk5AD-z6mnX4SeUmzY2VjaOlRybp2oudUbGzwft5PiVlyVs8-O8oBr_EwKdG8O5Hnxzfg5GRThfTPzjuha02CgXi1M892AlBqnU7RCc39I8vNH5XPEcyow_RghDjb4k1VSR-mZtiMCw; CST=91a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111; ID=TD=DB400FA09853FBF32BD51785C67BDB2F2EEB2D75:CS=2:A=1; IG-ENVIRONMENT=PROD; REFRESH-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9SRUZSRVNIIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ6aXAiOiJHWklQIn0.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXMuwoCMRCF4XdJbZFJMrlsJzZaCbs2lrlMlsAaxF1BEN_dKWw85cfhf4u8NOrbqYhBgAQFGLwSO_Fc6dHjjZiP-3G8eq8l82G6sASIUGR2MUHQimwIrtgMWCu44ABjVk7HAglzMWS9KcrZXEOKkowtVQKPay1uYgD02kgPDhnWlfNT6_NCU5v7ufOrp_r_otf9Bwja4ecLU4FikcUAAAA.CfStuGzJg4E4cDWuroNg5rj1vMsfmYjbkJfexIVfylwhBO_0WRiDQlyZ0G3RULW_6VpsQsR3qXj3UslUh79XY96fuCfLjFO5mP9EPO32j2Q72_WaT7NTb5HnTHv1xbblYwSOQwPraMaYwYkrDys14p5EDlPGNm9p3WXrk1s7-GZrvwryqcTgUfltvha2A_CG8odvzUqwP5ZTvs6Ua9fGDc7XTCAbmXq8IlutVCSNeR-8N10dfGVwzAsDe-wzEsGG3lDPuGbZuc29GgQIFpjEsVZuL0bw_JhiV57eknUBOC3NdsDSWk8p765Ex3V3SxT72Y0OUcZelteFLmWnUZNAgA; callerReqId=a122ee92484fefdd; client_id=a20fa8511e2a302574dddc5533444d0b; defaultDealingPlatform=PUREDEAL; deviceOs=Other; deviceType=Desktop; exitPath=uk; exitUrl=https://www.ig.com/uk; preferredAccountId=KY7KR; sessionOpen=true; AMCV_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18327%7CMCMID%7C50579323134050101141167903551723140495%7CMCAAMLH-1584012984%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1584012984%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1583415384s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18334%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2%7CMCCIDH%7C-1029498915; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; cpaEnabled=true; AAMC_iggroup_0=REGION%7C6; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10776225%2Caam%3D10776328%2Caam%3D10873328%2Caam%3D10873753%2Caam%3D10554416%2Caam%3D10800273%2Caam%3D10800207%2Caam%3D12237189%2Caam%3D14258131%2Caam%3D16895981%2Caam%3D11348465%2Caam%3D17467451; linkedinexcl=seg%3D10554416; aam_uuid=54084551990277770212092742170574063792; X-SECURITY-TOKEN=283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111; session_start_time=1583408194012; wtp:session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Aplatform%22%2C%22cst%22%3A%2291a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111%22%2C%22xst%22%3A%22283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111%22%7D%7D; lang=en-GB', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'Accept': '*/*'}
{'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Host': 'cdn.walkme.com', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'script', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'Accept': '*/*'}
{}
{}
{'Host': 'ec.walkme.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Origin': 'https://deal.ig.com', 'Content-Length': '1068', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01'}
{'Host': 'ec.walkme.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8', 'Origin': 'https://deal.ig.com', 'Content-Length': '399', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Accept': '*/*'}
{'Host': 'deal.ig.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Origin': 'https://deal.ig.com', 'Content-Length': '1417', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'Cookie': 'optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1583408158372r0.31262903776855944; _ga=GA1.2.3213041.1583408160; _gid=GA1.2.77060031.1583408160; _gat=1; AMCVS_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C50579323134050101141167903551723140495; _gcl_au=1.1.105363083.1583408170; _gat_UA-53269626-3=1; adviggroupigcomuklive=1; s_cvp_mktch19=%5B%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174937%27%5D%5D; s_nr2=1583408174936-New; gpv_pn=ex%20nav%3Alogin; s_cc=true; s_cvp_mktch28=%5B%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174934%27%5D%2C%5B%27DIR%27%2C%271583408174947%27%5D%5D; ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9BQ0NFU1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAifQ.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOvQrCMBQF4He5c4fcNMlNuomL0kFoXYo4pPkpgRrFtiCI724mwTN-HA7nDda5-5bXBZoLtAO1HVwrcHMKeT16aAAZcpRGc6hgW8Iz21sofNh13aB1zQrv-3MRgxY9c2RHNDUPyhjyyqGMEckQSus41dbjKJ0XQWnhOSkXzWhZEMpHhiVlLdkVGpS6FkwjyQJLOQd9ytMc-jTlUy6tPMb_Vng9fiBIfr50IW8W2gAAAA.qGsWbnN0LzmeCKkepN0vWY4z1sOYO6SgvNoPcQR3o6_6h8-5obpfQ_O1UQT1EOsPCxHJgibmX0_eHI8ll4gkY5oq75692T-1UU4nYJoXXW-iP1kNX-bV1Kba-sJybFWOywO_hp9wqKdko7jDGg7Ax8Q6JWb478enYZ8Y3VB2tzLMNMpK-J0RJyVt9_DRzkhvlguB7z1WdZluk5AD-z6mnX4SeUmzY2VjaOlRybp2oudUbGzwft5PiVlyVs8-O8oBr_EwKdG8O5Hnxzfg5GRThfTPzjuha02CgXi1M892AlBqnU7RCc39I8vNH5XPEcyow_RghDjb4k1VSR-mZtiMCw; CST=91a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111; ID=TD=DB400FA09853FBF32BD51785C67BDB2F2EEB2D75:CS=2:A=1; IG-ENVIRONMENT=PROD; REFRESH-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9SRUZSRVNIIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ6aXAiOiJHWklQIn0.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXMuwoCMRCF4XdJbZFJMrlsJzZaCbs2lrlMlsAaxF1BEN_dKWw85cfhf4u8NOrbqYhBgAQFGLwSO_Fc6dHjjZiP-3G8eq8l82G6sASIUGR2MUHQimwIrtgMWCu44ABjVk7HAglzMWS9KcrZXEOKkowtVQKPay1uYgD02kgPDhnWlfNT6_NCU5v7ufOrp_r_otf9Bwja4ecLU4FikcUAAAA.CfStuGzJg4E4cDWuroNg5rj1vMsfmYjbkJfexIVfylwhBO_0WRiDQlyZ0G3RULW_6VpsQsR3qXj3UslUh79XY96fuCfLjFO5mP9EPO32j2Q72_WaT7NTb5HnTHv1xbblYwSOQwPraMaYwYkrDys14p5EDlPGNm9p3WXrk1s7-GZrvwryqcTgUfltvha2A_CG8odvzUqwP5ZTvs6Ua9fGDc7XTCAbmXq8IlutVCSNeR-8N10dfGVwzAsDe-wzEsGG3lDPuGbZuc29GgQIFpjEsVZuL0bw_JhiV57eknUBOC3NdsDSWk8p765Ex3V3SxT72Y0OUcZelteFLmWnUZNAgA; callerReqId=a122ee92484fefdd; client_id=a20fa8511e2a302574dddc5533444d0b; defaultDealingPlatform=PUREDEAL; deviceOs=Other; deviceType=Desktop; exitPath=uk; exitUrl=https://www.ig.com/uk; preferredAccountId=KY7KR; sessionOpen=true; AMCV_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18327%7CMCMID%7C50579323134050101141167903551723140495%7CMCAAMLH-1584012984%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1584012984%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1583415384s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18334%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2%7CMCCIDH%7C-1029498915; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; cpaEnabled=true; linkedinexcl=seg%3D10554416; aam_uuid=54084551990277770212092742170574063792; AAMC_iggroup_0=REGION%7C6; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10776225%2Caam%3D10776328%2Caam%3D10873328%2Caam%3D10873753%2Caam%3D10554416%2Caam%3D10800273%2Caam%3D10800207%2Caam%3D12237189%2Caam%3D14258131%2Caam%3D16895981%2Caam%3D11348465%2Caam%3D17467451; X-SECURITY-TOKEN=283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111; session_start_time=1583408194012; wtp:session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Aplatform%22%2C%22cst%22%3A%2291a1d0c7ab1932e6997d6c15ff179715ac273ad1b5cd4e684d276cf9ba0e46df01111%22%2C%22xst%22%3A%22283f5a46528c57fffa30c7bfb7dfa50fed42d92c1316723dd9844aa0e8dec2f801111%22%7D%7D; lang=en-GB', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'Accept': '*/*'}
{'Host': 'ec.walkme.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Origin': 'https://deal.ig.com', 'Content-Length': '955', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01'}
{'Host': 'col.eum-appdynamics.com', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Referer': 'https://deal.ig.com/wtp', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Origin': 'https://deal.ig.com', 'Content-Length': '2142', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site', 'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Accept': '*/*'}
```

I want to save it to a file, here is my code:

```
for ent in proxy.har['log']['entries']:
    url = ent['request']['headers']
    response = ent['response']
    #print(ent['request']['headers'])
    headers = {e['name']: e['value'] for e in ent['request']['headers']}
    print(headers)
    #time.sleep(20)
    with open('har.txt', 'w') as har:
        json.dump(headers, har)
```

The har.txt file for some reason only saves the last row from the har file, not sure why thats happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Only last line is saved to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115140/python-only-last-line-is-saved-to-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `open('...','w')` you are erasing the content of the file on every loop.  Open it in append mode so id doesn't get erased:

```
open('har.txt', 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('har.txt', 'a') as har:
```

use 'a' to append.. not 'w' to write